# Wpf Dropshadow remove offset

Tags: wpf, xaml, offset, dropshadow

Is there a way to set shadow effect with 0 offset?

It's ugly when I set this effect on a border. I am trying to reproduce the box-shadow css property

[image: here in my hud]

Here a sample of code to have some context:

```
<Border 
    BorderThickness="1,0,0,1"
    Grid.Column="1"
    Grid.Row="0"
    >
        <Border.Effect>
            <DropShadowEffect Direction="360" ShadowDepth="5" />
        </Border.Effect>

        ...

</Border>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
<DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="3" BlurRadius="3" Opacity="0.5" />
```

You probably want to give your Border some margin too, else the shadow will expand further than you want

Comment: I think you forgot something xD

Comment: Ahh sorry! Still getting used to the StackOverflow formatting - didn't realise that if I didn't put 4 spaces at the start of the line it would eat my code!

Comment: A bit better but the offset still here

Answer (score 0):

Set `ShadowDepth` to 0, this can remove offset completely.

```xml
<DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="12" Opacity="1" Color="Red" />
```

[image]

`ShadowDepth` controls offset size, and `Direction` controls angle

```xml
<DropShadowEffect Direction="180" BlurRadius="12" ShadowDepth="12" Color="red"/>
```

[image]